# Ajax call and socket call are not working in the same file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, sockets

There is a php file in my project which is about handling socket calls (notice that my project is a website with a multiplayer game). For some reasons I need to use an ajax call in this file. But whenever I do this none of the socket part of the file and the ajax part work any longer, and PHP throws this error:

> socket_bind(): unable to bind address [10048]: Only one usage of each
> socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Is there any way that I can use both socket and ajax at the same time?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Assets/SourceCodes/require.js"></script>
<script>
        var rCards = 0;
        var n = 1;
        var s = 1;
        for(var i = 0; i < 63; i++){
            rCards[i] = new RegularCard(n, giveShapeName(s), s, giveShapeName(s));
            if(n == 9){
                n = 1;
                if(s == 7){
                    s = 1;
                }
                else {
                    s = s + 1;
                }
            }
            else{
                n = n + 1;
            }
        }
        var sCards = [
            new SpecialCard("S_Dot", 1,  "cyan", null, "Dot"),
            new SpecialCard("S_Line", 2,"blue", null, "Sline"),
            new SpecialCard("S_Tri", 3,  "pruple", null, "Tri"),
            new SpecialCard("S_Sqr", 4,  "red", null, "Sqr"),
            new SpecialCard("S_Pen", 5, "orange", null, "Pen"),
            new SpecialCard("S_Hex", 6,  "yellow", null, "Hex"),
            new SpecialCard("S_Hep", 7,  "green", null, "Hep"),
        ];
        var jsonTask = {
            RegularCards: rCards,
            SpecialCards: sCards,
        };
        var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(jsonTask);
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
           console.log("response:"+xhttp.responseText);
        }
        xhttp.open("POST", `server.php?q=${jsonStr}`, true);
        xhttp.send();
</script>
<?php
class player{
    public $id;
    public $cards;
    function __construct($id,$cards)
    {   
        $this->id = $id;
            $this->cards = $cards;
        }
    }
    class room{
        public $id;
        public $players;
        public $cardStack;
        public $specialCardStack;
        function __construct($id,$players,$cardStack,$specialCardStack)
        {
            $this->id = $id;
            $this->players = $players;
            $this->cardStack = $cardStack;
            $this->specialCardStack = $specialCardStack;
        }
}
function ShuffleCards($_ary){
    $res = $_ary;
    $temp = null;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($res);$i++){
        $a = rand(0,count($res)-1);
        $b = rand(0,count($res)-1);
        $temp = $res[$a];
        $res[$a] = $res[$b];
        $res[$b] = $temp;
    }
    return $res;
}
if(isset($_POST["q"])){
    $cards = $_GET["q"];
    $cardsJson = json_decode($cards);
    $regCards = $cardsJson->RegularCards;
    $spcCards = $cardsJson->SpecialCards;
    $rooms = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
        $temp = new room($i,[],ShuffleCards($regCards),ShuffleCards($spcCards));
        array_push($rooms,$temp);
    }   
}
//---------------------------------socket-------------------------------------------
set_time_limit(0);
$close = false;
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$port = 4324;
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
$spawn = "";
while(!$close){
    $result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
        $spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
        $input = socket_read($spawn, 100000000 ) or die("Could not read input\n");
        $output ="emptyOutput";
        $jsonTask = json_decode($input);
        $task = $jsonTask->task;
        if($task == "GiveRooms"){
            global $rooms;
            $jsonFile = json_encode($rooms);
            $output = $jsonFile;
        }
        else if($task == "Close"){
            $close = true;
            $jsonFile = array(
                "msg" => "server has closed",
            );
            $output = json_encode($jsonFile);
        }
        socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write output\n");
        socket_close($spawn);
    }
    socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Comment: Class inside class?

Comment: @MarkusZeller it seems like it from the indentation. but it actually isn't.

Comment: You could try `$host = "0.0.0.0";` or the direct IP address instead of localhost.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` did not worked

Comment: Perhaps you've got more than one instance of this PHP script running at the same time - and you can't create more than one listener on the same port, so that wouldn't work. Do some debugging, perhaps.